# Migrating log4j using bridge and DOMConfigurator?

Tags: java, log4j

I like to migrate from an older 1.2.x version of log4j, according to the docs I can use the bridge (log4j-1.2-api-2.15.0.jar), but one of the requirements is:

"They must not configure by calling the classes DOMConfigurator or PropertyConfigurator"

Unfortunately we're using the DOMConfigurator to set our logging configuration.

If I remove this - is the bridge looking for an log4j.xml now and can it read the old config format? Or must I convert the config file to the new format and name it log4j2.xml?
Would removing the DOMConfigurator code and place and log4j.xml or log4j2.xml in the classpath work?

Thanks
Klaus

Comment: Does this answer your question? [log4j-slf4j-impl / log4j v2 - setting custom log4j.xml destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70352815/log4j-slf4j-impl-log4j-v2-setting-custom-log4j-xml-destination)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this works.

I can disable the DOMConfigurator and use an log4j2.xml in the classpath - just have to transfer the config settings to the new format.

Comment: Try [`Log4j1ConfigurationConverter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-1.2-api/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/config/Log4j1ConfigurationConverter.html) for a preliminary `log4j2.xml` conversion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).