# log4j-slf4j-impl / log4j v2 - setting custom log4j.xml destination

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

At runtime in my application, I'd like to specify the location of the log4j configuration file dynamically.

This is so that rather than this being a resource bundled in the JAR, it's an actual file on disk that can be edited if there is a problem to increase logging levels.

When using log4j v1.2, you can use `DOMConfigurator.configure(URL)` to do this.

But now I've upgraded to log4j-slf4j-impl / log4j v2, this method no longer exists.

I can see how to configure log4j directly, but I want to use the existing slf4j compatible XML file without having to change it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4j 2.x uses a [`ConfigurationFactory`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/ConfigurationFactory.html) to parse a configuration file. There is a factory for each format and a default factory. The default factory tries to guess the correct format from the file extension of the file: unfortunately both the old Log4j 1.2 and the new Log4j 2.x formats have an `.xml` extension, so additional configuration is needed.

In order to parse the Log4j 1.2 XML format you need to add the [`log4j-1.2.api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-1.2-api) artifact and replace the default factory:

```java
import org.apache.log4j.xml.XmlConfigurationFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory;

ConfigurationFactory.setConfigurationFactory(new XmlConfigurationFactory());
```

After this is set a simple:

```java
Configurator.reconfigure(new URI("URI of your file"));
```

will apply your configuration to the appropriate `LoggerContext`.