# Replacement of DOM configurator in log4j2 in java

Tags: logging, log4j2

Can someone please let me know how to replace DOM configurator while migrating from log4j 1.x to log4j 2.x.I could not find DOM configurator in log4j2.It would be helpful if someone could share sample code how to use DOM configurator in log4j2.(my requirement is to configure url)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [log4j-slf4j-impl / log4j v2 - setting custom log4j.xml destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70352815/log4j-slf4j-impl-log4j-v2-setting-custom-log4j-xml-destination)

Comment: I could not find Configurator.reconfigure,it shows no method reconfigure found for configurator.I have added all the dependencies and necessary imports.Kindly help.

Comment: [`Configurator#reconfigure(Configuration)`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configurator.html) was added in version 2.13.0. Which version are you using?

Comment: Thanks,i am using version 2.3.2. Even after upgrading to version 2 and placing log4j2.xml in resource folder inam getting error"log4j: ERROR DOM element is not a log4j: configuration element.Can you please help?

Comment: The 2.3.x branch contains security fixes, but no enhancements (cf. [LOG4J2-3390](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3390). You need to consider migrating to Java 8, since Java 6 does not have security fixes.